# Validating Image Load in Nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to write a script in Nightwatch.js to verify that the images on a given page are loading correctly. I've managed to get it to cycle through the images on a page and give me the URLs, but I haven't been able to get it to load the image and return the width/height. (With the idea of checking to make sure that the width is > 0 to ensure that it loaded correctly.)

I get the "done" message in the script below, but never see the "loaded...", width, height, or "!!!!" values output.

I'm also completely open to different approaches to using Nightwatch.js to validate that the images have loaded, but the objective of the current exercise is to use Nightwatch.js. (We are also looking into other broken-image checks, but I'm exploring rolling it in with the other testing we're doing with Nightwatch.js.)

```
  browser.elements('css selector', 'img', function(result) {
    for (var element in result.value) {
      this.elementIdAttribute(result.value[element].ELEMENT,'src',function(result) {
        console.log(result.value);
        var imgwidth = browser.execute(function(result) {
          var img = new Image();

          img.onload = function() {

            console.log('loaded...');

            var width = img.naturalWidth,
                height = img.naturalHeight;

            console.log(width);
            console.log(height);

          };
          img.src = result.value;

          console.log('!!!!!');

        });

      console.log('done');


      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightwatch already provides a native method for getting the size of an element, `.getElementSize(selector, callback)`

http://nightwatchjs.org/api/getElementSize.html